# How to read position from each row using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

How to read position value from txt file ? like i have text file with multiple row data in the text file.

```
10234511234preview compostion 12345  
2034512344566345644444  
2344455555555  
2100000034567
```

Now i want to read position `7 to 10` from first row and match my constant value and position `11 to 18` again with constant value.
same way have to do that for the second row.

So starting two digits are 10,20 the key values for each rows.

Please help me how to do the VBA code for above scenario ?

Comment: I tried with Mid(strLine, 10, 5) to get the 5 characters at position 10 from strLine

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to your question, I have used below one for one of my automation using VBA.

I will suggest you to use two sheets(say Input and Output of same workbook) where Input sheet should have data from your text file and Output sheet will give you data starting from specific positions(say 10,20).

Add a button on Input sheet and write below code on its click event(Paste your data from C7 cell from text file):

First get the total number of rows using below code:

`usedRowCount = Worksheets("Input").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Then use below code for copying string from specific location and paste it on Output sheet using below code:

```
For i = 1 To usedRowCount

'Get the first row in variable strRecord

strRecord = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, "C").Value        
'Copy substring from 10th posotion, 6 characters and copy it to sheet Output position A1  
Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, "A").Value = Mid(CStr(strRecord), 10, 6)    
'Copy substring from 20th posotion, 8 characters and copy it to sheet Output position B1  
Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, "B").Value = Mid(CStr(strRecord), 20, 8)    
'Copy substring from 30th posotion, 4 characters and copy it to sheet Output position C1  
Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, "C").Value = Mid(CStr(strRecord), 30, 4)    
next i
```